# How do I encode the bin-packing problem into chromosomes for a genetic algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to develop my understanding of genetic algorithms.

I have found great explanations for how to run a genetic algorithm for the knapsack problem [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339771109_Solving_Knapsack_Problem_with_Genetic_Algorithm_Approach) and the travelling salesman problem [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311709380_A_New_Approach_using_Binary_Encoding_to_Solve_Travelling_Salesman_Problem_with_Genetic_Algorithms), and I understand these processes now, and from these papers, I understand how to encode these problems into chromosomes (as described in the papers linked).

I'm struggling to understand how this translates to the bin-packing problem (described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)) so as to begin understanding the algorithm. Could someone show me a sample of how to encode the bin-packing problem into chromosomes just with a small amount of toy data to start me off?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier with float-valued genes, as in the [BRKGA](https://www.google.com/search?q=brkga) framework. Then you can (e.g.) have one gene per item and decode a chromosome by sorting the corresponding item using the genes to compare, and then turning the order into packed bins by running a simple online approximation algorithm like [next-fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#Next-Fit_(NF)).